# How do I dual boot my android ice cream sandwich tablet with ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, android, tablet

I have android 4.04 ice cream sandwich as it was pre installed. I have an archos 80 cobalt. How would I dual boot with ubuntu?

Comment: Archos is not a supported target device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the exact solution to your problem because it installs a full desktop and not the mobile version, but this is what I had to do because my tablet isn't supported either.

Step 1: Root your tablet. **Warning: This may void your warranty.**

Here's some instructions for your particular tablet. (Please note that I haven't tried
these  instructions because I don't have an Archos80 Cobalt):
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2066972

Step 2: Download "Complete Linux Installer" by ZPWEBSITES from Google Play.

Step 3: Install your chosen flavor.